# Playing sound on web pages isn't working on iPod Touch (using Safari)

Tags: ipod-touch

I've noticed that the embedded mp3 file on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_soundmidiembed) won't play at all on my iPod Touch (using the Safari web browser), even though it seems to be working properly in Google Chrome on Windows 7. Is there any way to allow embedded mp3 files (in web pages) to play properly on an iPod Touch, using Safari?

Comment: My iPod Touch is either 4th generation or 5th generation (but I'm not sure which one).

Comment: This Google search results page may be relevant: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+play+sound+iphone&oq=javascript+play+sound+ip&gs_l=hp.3.1.0j0i30j0i8i30.1349.5799.1.7973.24.24.0.0.0.0.165.2053.18j6.24.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.CRQPEqqO_NY&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41934586,d.dmg&fp=4c43c234fb497faf&biw=1366&bih=631